# How to read data stream ignoring the data type in Java

Tags: java, io, socket.io, client-server, sip

I am writing a client-server application in `Java`. The procedure is as following:

1. A client send a message of HTTP format to a registration node with

   - a request line a number of header lines
   - a blank line
   - and a body.
   - (ASCII text)
2. The registration node send a message of similar format to a server.
3. The client and server can talk (pretty like SIP).

For now, I already have created sockets of client and server, but if I want to use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to input and output data, I also need to determine the type of data since methods like readDouble from DataInputStream.

I don't know how to do it.

Sorry if my description is a little ambiguous, Here, some sample messages that would be transferred.

```
REGISTER john@google.com SIPL/1.0CRLF
To: john@google.comCRLF
From: john@google.comCRLF
Call-ID: a74fbCRLF
CSeq: 0CRLF
Expires: 200CRLF
Contact: 74.125.226.161:20132CRLF
CRLF

SIPL/1.0 200 okCRLF
To: barney@google.comCRLF
From: 74.125.226.161:20300CRLF
Call-ID: 9934bcd2CRLF
CSeq: 10CRLF
Content-Length: 21CRLF
Contact: 74.125.226.161:20305CRLF
CRLF
file=foo
characters=10
```

Any apply will really be appreciated !!!

Comment: If everything is HTTP headers and ASCII text why do you want to to deal with types like double? Perhaps using a reader (via InputStreamReader) would be more appropriate?

Comment: A `DataInputStream`'s `.readDouble()` will read 8 bytes which it expects to be a _binary representation_ of the double; given your dump, this is not what you want...

Comment: I just set an example about the data stream input. So what is the best way to input&output these data? still data stream? or something else like scanner, printwriter etc.?@fge @helderdarocha

Comment: Just use the methods of InputStream and OutputStream.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, InputStream and OutputStream are good ways to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are reading ASCII text, and have to deal with line breaks, you can use readers and writers, and read your data with a `java.io.BufferedReader` which allows you to read line by line.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String line = reader.readLine();
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
while ( line != null) {
   buffer.append(line);
   line = reader.readLine();

   // you can check here if the line is empty and decide only to read the header
   // or to split your header and body into different buffers

}
String fullText = buffer.toString();
```

If you send text data, you can also use something similar:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
writer.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
writer.println("Header: value");
writer.println(); // end of header
...
writer.flush(); // if you need to flush the buffer before closing
writer.close(); // when done - flushes and closes
```

Place everything in a `try-catch-finally` block with the `close()` methods in the `finally` (or, if you use Java 7, a try-with-resources)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Isn't PrintWriter for text i/o, while BufferedReader is for binary i/o?

Comment: @helderdarcocha What if I want to transfer .dat file?

Comment: Readers and Writers are for character I/O. Raw data streams (InputStream and OutputStream) are for binary I/О. The InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter are wrappers that convert a binary streams into character streams.

Comment: If you have content that is not text, your header files should include some kind of information about the MIME type of the attachment, so that you can, after the header is finished, know when you can switch to reading the raw stream directly.

Comment: Just like the samples I showed, is it good to consider them all as lines of string? @helderdarcocha

Comment: The samples you showed can be safely read as strings. That doesn't mean you can't parse strings later to extract data from the body and interpret it as something else (for example, you might be interested in extracting from the `characters=10` line the number `10`, which you can do so by parsing the body, extracting the values and parsing strings into numbers with functions like `Integer.parseInt()`)

Comment: You need to specify the line terminator explicitly as `\r\n` for HTTP. Relying on the platform default via `println()` is not adequate except on those platforms where it happens to *be* `\r\n.`

Comment: No println() is required because of CRLF. That is my question: how to extract the information without knowing its type. I can only use parseInt() if I know it it int type. Other, what is the option?

Comment: You will need some kind of metadata or schema so you know how to extract certain text data as different types. Usually data headers describe the data media type or attachments, but if your data is somehow structured (like a CSV, XML) you will need some kind of schema to describe which lines, which tokens, which characters are one type or another.

Comment: what if not that complicated? just text or binary stream, do I need to  add some headers like "Expires: " to determine the next input is int type?

Comment: If what follows the headers is a binary stream, you should have a header like `Content-type: image/jpg` for example. If it's a series of types (`DataInput`), then you can use the data methods for ints, floats, etc. but you still need to know what's coming (after a delimiter, or based on a certain number of bytes read, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to recognize the header using bufferedreader. For example, if i want to read 'Expires: 200CRLF'  I need to recognize the header is 'Expires: ', so that I know next I need to parse int. How to do that? Thank you very much!!! @helderdarocha

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to recognize the header using bufferedreader. For example, if i want to read 'Expires: 200CRLF' I need to recognize the header is 'Expires: ', so that I know next I need to parse int. How to do that? Thank you very much!!! @EJP

Comment: If you read one `line` at a time using `readLine()` it splits the lines by the CRLF, so for each line you can get the header name and header value by finding the first ":" and splitting on it. You can do `int semicolon = line.indexOf(":");` and then `String headerName = line.substring(0, semicolon);` to get the header, and `String headerValue = line.substring(semicolon+1, line.length()).trim();` You test which header you read (`if (headerName.equals("Expires")) { ... }`) and if it should contain a number, you can do `Integer.parseInt(headerValue)`.

Comment: when I send the expires data, i am using the format:     "output.print(expires + 200 + crlf);" @helderdarocha
and "String crlf = "\r\n"" "String expires = "Expires: ""

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think in this case, using " " to split is better. is there a simplier format to do it? Since there are at least 5 header lines at each protocol message, and more than 5 kinds of actions........ @helderdarocha

Comment: You can also use the `split()` method which converts a string in an array, but it's also trickier since it takes a regexp (you have to escape periods, for example) and it will get *all* the `:` (it will split your `Contact` in three parts, since it has a `:` in the value.) String parsers aren't trivial. Using `indexOf` and `substring` is good for beginners. If you wan't more flexibility, then find some time to study regexp and parsers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!@helderdarocha   Actually, I have learned regular expression and parsers. However, I don't know how to define the array type if split the string into array.

Comment: It should be an array of string: `String[] array = line.split(" ");`

Comment: what if the substring is int type? does the array need to be int?

Comment: No. You only convert to int after you've isolated the number in the string, and if you need to convert it. `int number = Integer.parseInt("123");`

Comment: Got it. I just need to declare a new int type variable to store parseInt(array[1]). It is way more convenient! MUCH APPRECIATED!!! @helderdarocha